# Correct way to cascate promises for arrays (mongoose example)

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I need to understand the correct way to cascade promises using mongoose.

My function `createCustomerBills` with receive a list of customer id's that, for each one, I need to create a simple bill.

Here is the code:

```
const createCustomerBill = (customer) => {
    return BillModel.create({
        customer_id: customer.id,
        value: 100
    });
}

const createCustomerBills => (customerIds) => {
    let criteria = {
        _id: { $in: customerIds }
    };

    return CustomerModel.find(criteria)
    .then(result => {
        return result.map(customer => {
            return createCustomerBill(customer);
        }
    })
    .then(result => {
        return CustomerModel.update(
                { _id: customer.id }, 
                { status: "BillCreated" }
        );
    });
}
```

Here is the steps:
1. Get list of all customers
2. For each customer, create the bill
3. For each bill created, update the customer status

I need an advice if this is the correct method of doing it and possible drawbacks.

Comment: is `createCustomerBill` at all asynchronous? also, you seem to be running `CustomerModel.update` only **once** rather than once for each bill

Comment: Yes, I need all to be asyncronous, and in fact my understanding is that createCustomerBill is asyncronous (as mongoose create is asynchronous). Am I wrong?

Comment: then you're doing it wrong, because `return result.map` returns an array, immediately, so there's no "waiting" before  `CustomerModel.update` is called

Comment: Umm... So seens that the update status piece of code needs to be a `then` of `createCustomerBill: createCustomerBill(customer).then(...)`, inside the map, right? (this is the kind of advice I need...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are mapping the result of `CustomerModel.find`, returning that array wont wait for the promises to complete to run the next .then, as an array is not a Promise

That's where Promise.all comes in

Also, as you need to update each bill individually, that part of the promise chain needs to be inside the `.map` iteration

```
const createCustomerBill = customer => 
    BillModel.create({
        customer_id: customer.id,
        value: 100
    });

const createCustomerBills => customerIds => {
    let criteria = {
        _id: { $in: customerIds }
    };

    return CustomerModel.find(criteria)
    .then(result => 
        Promise.all(
            result.map(customer => createCustomerBill(customer)
                .then(result => CustomerModel.update({ _id: customer.id }, { status: "BillCreated" }))
            )
        )
    )
    .then(result => {
        // all bills are now processed 
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do I need `Promise.all`.. Returning just the map result (`return result.map(...).then(...)` woldn't be an array of promises? What is the difference between these 2 returns?

Comment: you need to wait for **all** the promises ... you'd only need this if the code that calls `createCustomerBills` needs to wait for the process to finish ... if it doesn't then you don't even need to return anything

Comment: Got it! Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible working way, IMO

```js
const createCustomerBill = (customer) => {
  return BillModel.create({
    customer_id: customer.id,
    value: 100,
  });
}

const createCustomerBills => (customerIds) => {
  const criteria = {
    _id: {
      $in: customerIds,
    },
  };

  return CustomerModel.find(criteria)
    .then((customers) => Promise.all(customers.map(x => createCustomerBill(x)
      .then(() => CustomerModel.update({
        _id: x.id,
      }, {
        status: "BillCreated"
      })))))
    .then(() => console.log('over'))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

---

And here using the awesome `async/await`

```js
const createCustomerBill = customer => BillModel.create({
  customer_id: customer.id,
  value: 100,
});

const updateCustomer = customer => CustomerModel.update({
  _id: x.id,
}, {
  status: 'BillCreated',
});

const createBillAndUpdateCustomer = async(customer) => {
  await createCustomerBill(customer);
  
  await updateCustomer(customer);
};

const createCustomerBills => async(customerIds) => {
  const customers = await CustomerModel.find({
    _id: {
      $in: customerIds,
    },
  });

  await Promise.all(customers.map(x => createBillAndUpdateCustomer(x)));

  console.log('over');
}
```